# Forming blocks with temporally connected observations in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently trying to identify temporally adjacent observations in a dataset.

In the example df_1 you see 5 observations and I would like to get the df_result from them. The end date of id=3 is exactly one day before the start date of id=4, so I want to merge both into one larger block with the name of the later observation.

```
df_1 = data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  start=c("2018-01-01", "2018-02-20", "2018-03-15", "2018-03-20", "2018-04-01"),
                  end=c("2018-01-10", "2018-02-25", "2018-03-19", "2018-03-30", "2018-04-05")
                  )
```

```
df_result1 = data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 4, 5),
                  start=c("2018-01-01", "2018-02-20", "2018-03-15", "2018-04-01"),
                  end=c("2018-01-10", "2018-02-25", "2018-03-30", "2018-04-05"),
                  flag=c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

If there should be even more than 2 observations, which it concerns, then there should be of course also still longer fusions.

Greetings and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option where we convert the date columns to `Date` class, then create a 'flag' logical column based on the difference between the next value of 'start and current 'end', check if the difference is less than or equal to 1, get the cumulative sum of the logical 'flag' as grouping column, and `summarise`, by taking the `last` or first`value of the columns`if`there are`any`TRUE in 'flag' or`else` return the column values

```
library(dplyr)
df_1 %>%
  mutate(across(c(start, end), as.Date)) %>%
  mutate(flag = as.numeric(lead(start, default = last(start)) - end) <= 1 ) %>%
 group_by(grp = cumsum(flag)) %>% 
 summarise(id = if(any(flag)) last(id) else id, 
           start = if(any(flag)) first(start) else start, 
           end  = if(any(flag)) last(end) else end, 
           flag = any(flag) & n() > 1, .groups = 'drop') %>%
select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#     id start      end        flag 
#  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <lgl>
#1     1 2018-01-01 2018-01-10 FALSE
#2     2 2018-02-20 2018-02-25 FALSE
#3     4 2018-03-15 2018-03-30 TRUE 
#4     5 2018-04-01 2018-04-05 FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you, I have to fix a Bug with the datatype: Fehler: Problem with `mutate()` input `flag`.
x nicht anwendbare Methode für 'lead' auf Objekt der Klasse "Date" angewendet

Comment: @edstrinova can you please show the error message in english

Comment: Problem with `mutate()` input `flag`. Inapplicable method for "lead" applied to object of  class "Date". Input `flag` is `as.numeric(lead(start, default = last(start)) - end) <= 1`.

Comment: @edstrinova Not clear about that error message.  I am using `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.2’`. Do you have a recent dplyr package version

Comment: @edstrinova Also, just to be clear, is the error on the same example or on a different dataset?

Comment: On the example.

Comment: @edstrinova What is your `packageVersion('dplyr')` and R version

Comment: My Versions are like yours: dplyr 1.0.2, R 4.0.3 and RStudio 1.3.1093.

Comment: ℹ Input `flag` is `as.numeric(lead(start, default = last(start)) - end) <= 1`.
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::mutate(., across(c(start, end), as.Date))
  2. dplyr::mutate(...)
 15. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: It was my mistake because the function lead was masked by another package. Excuse me. I will now test the code on the target data. The first attempt failed. When I know more, I will adjust the example accordingly.